# SQL Query replace string with placeholder

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, mariadb

My table has lots of entries (image paths). Such a string is an URL and looks like that

```
https://example.com/images/do.php?id=1234
```

And i have to change them all to this format

```
https://example.com/images/1234.png
```

So the "ID" is equal to the filename. Replacing just the URL isn't that hard, but i have to add the static file extension, which is in my case "png" at the end of the URL string. So i need something like that

```
UPDATE post SET message = REPLACE(message, 'https://example.com/images/do.php?id=', 'https://example.com/images/{id}.png');
```

I'm absolutely no experienced SQL user, so can you please help me out?

**Edit//**

Now i have entries like that:

```
https://example.com/images/1234
https://example.com/images/5678
```

What is the query that i need to add the static file extension? So my entries looks like that:

```
https://example.com/images/1234.png
https://example.com/images/5678.png
```

The length of the ID's are between 4 to 6 characters. The main problem here why i can't just add the extension is, because my message row does contain more text than just the URL to modify. Such a row can look like that:

```
Here is your image link: [LINK]https://example.com/images/1234.png[/LINK] You can view it now.
```

**Edit2//**

My DB table named "post" does look as follows

```
id   |   message
----------------
1    |   test
2    |   Here is your image link: [LINK]https://example.com/images/1234[/LINK] You can view it now.
3    |   some strings
4    |   Here is your image link: [LINK]https://example.com/images/5678[/LINK] You can view it now.
5    |   [LINK]no correct url[/LINK]
6    |   [LINK][IMG]https://example.com/images/9123[/IMG][/LINK]
7    |   [LINK]https://example.com/images/912364[/LINK]
```

So not every message row does contain an url and not every message with a [LINK]-tag does contain a proper url. Also there are enrties which have a longer ID, they should not be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answers the original version of the question.

This works for the example in your question:

```
select concat(substring_index(path, 'do.php', 1),
              substring_index(path, '=', -1),
              '.png')
from (select 'https://example.com/images/do.php?id=1234' as path) x
```

You can easily turn this to an `update`:

```
update post
    set message = concat(substring_index(message, 'do.php', 1),
                         substring_index(message, '=', -1),
                         '.png')
    where message like '%do.php%=%';
```

Comment: IS that the complete query?

Comment: There are hundreds of these URLs stored, which i have to replace. So di i need to use UPDATE statement in addition?

Comment: Thanks for your update. Unfortunately, after the query, the URLs are looking like that:  "h**ps://example.com/images/"

Comment: @andy  . . . Run the `select` and see if it returns what you want.  You also specify "url" in your descriptions, but put a column called `message` in the code.

Comment: It worked i made a typo, thank you very much Gordon!

Comment: I made a mistake, i've edited my question above. How can i just add the static file extension do all of my "dynamic" url entries?

Comment: @andy . . . That seems like a different question and should be asked as a *new* question.  Your original question was answered.

Comment: You're right. I asked a new question regarding my current issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60433095/sql-query-with-regexp-to-change-url-strings-dynamically

Answer (score 1):

For your second problem:

```
UPDATE post
SET message = concat(message,'.png')
```

Just extend your current entry with '.png' :-)

**EDIT:** So, my bad! You should give Regex a try:

```
UPDATE post
SET message = CONCAT(REGEXP_SUBSTR(path,'.*https:\/\/example\.com\/images\/[0-9]{4,6}'),'.png',REGEXP_SUBSTR(path,'\[\/LINK\].*'))
```

This statement asserts that there is no file extension existing. So you can run the statement without where clause because the file extension won't get doubled. 
For being sure you can check it before with:

```
SELECT
    message
    ,CONCAT(REGEXP_SUBSTR(path,'.*https:\/\/example\.com\/images\/[0-9]{4,6}'),'.png',REGEXP_SUBSTR(path,'\[\/LINK\].*')) as corr_message
FROM path
```

Check the pattern as well on e.g. [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) with your given example as string

```
Here is your image link: [LINK]https://example.com/images/1234[/LINK] You can view it now.
```

and the following as pattern

```
(.*https:\/\/example\.com\/images\/[0-9]{4,6})(\[\/LINK\].*)
```

The parenthesis builds groups. The first group is for the first part of the string. In update, this is the first Part of Concat. Afterwards we will set '.png'. The third part withing your update statement is represent with the second group of the regex-pattern.

Hope, this will help you. :)

**EDIT2:** Alright, this will fit to your rows.

```
UPDATE post
SET message = CONCAT(REGEXP_SUBSTR(path,'.*https:\/\/example\.com\/images\/[0-9]{4,6}'),'.png',REGEXP_SUBSTR(path,'\[\/(IMG|LINK)\].*')) 
WHERE message LIKE '%https://example.com/images/%'
```

Pattern for checking it:

```
(.*https:\/\/example\.com\/images\/[0-9]{4,6})(\[\/(IMG|LINK)\].*)
```

As select for checking your data before update:

```
SELECT
    message
    ,CONCAT(REGEXP_SUBSTR(path,'.*https:\/\/example\.com\/images\/[0-9]{4,6}'),'.png',REGEXP_SUBSTR(path,'\[\/(IMG|LINK)\].*')) as corr_message
FROM path
WHERE message LIKE '%https://example.com/images/%'
```

Hope this fits now for your case :)

Comment: The problem is that there is more text inside the message row than just the url...That's why my idea is to have some sort of placeholder for the ID's. I've edited that in my question

Comment: That's one step closer, but it does also select other message rows, where e.g. only some text is stored in.

Comment: I've edited my question and added the scheme of my db table