# SQL Query with REGEXP to change URL strings dynamically

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, mariadb

My DB table named "post" does look as follows

```
id   |   message
----------------
1    |   test
2    |   Here is your image link: [LINK]https://example.com/images/1234[/LINK] You can view it now.
3    |   some strings
4    |   Here is your image link: [LINK]https://example.com/images/5678[/LINK] You can view it now.
5    |   [LINK]no correct url[/LINK]
6    |   [LINK][IMG]https://example.com/images/9123[/IMG][/LINK]
7    |   [LINK]https://example.com/images/912364[/LINK]
8    |   [LINK]Some text https://example.com/images/23456 Text again[/LINK]
9    |   [URL="https://example.com/images/10796"]
```

So not every message row does contain an url and not every message with a [LINK]-tag does contain a proper url. Also there are enrties which have a longer ID, they should not be changed.

Now i have to change every entry which has an ID length between 4 and 5 characters:

```
https://example.com/images/1234
https://example.com/images/5678
```

To that format -> adding a file extension

```
https://example.com/images/1234.png
https://example.com/images/5678.png
```

So the "ID" is equal to the filename. Replacing just the URL isn't that hard, but i have to add the static file extension, which is in my case ".png" at the end of the URL string.

**Edit//**

At the end, my DB table should look like that

```
id   |   message
----------------
1    |   test
2    |   Here is your image link: [LINK]https://example.com/images/1234.png[/LINK] You can view it now.
3    |   some strings
4    |   Here is your image link: [LINK]https://example.com/images/5678.png[/LINK] You can view it now.
5    |   [LINK]no correct url[/LINK]
6    |   [LINK][IMG]https://example.com/images/9123.png[/IMG][/LINK]
7    |   [LINK]https://example.com/images/912364[/LINK]
8    |   [LINK]Some text https://example.com/images/23456.png Text again[/LINK]
9    |   [URL="https://example.com/images/10796.png"]
```

That adding the file extension to the URL only where the "URL-ID" has 4 or 5 digits and only if the URL matches.

I'm absolutely no experienced SQL user.

Comment: . . Edit your question and show the final result you want *for all rows*.

Comment: I just made the edit

Comment: Is it possible that 2 or more [LINK]..[/LINK] occures in one message? Especially when one is correct whereas another is not...

Comment: *At the end, my DB table should look like that* Why the link in `id=7` is not updated?

Comment: @Akina, Yes it is possible, that multiple [LINK]-Tags occur. id=7 is not updated, because the "ID-part" of the URL at the end has 6 digits, where the query should only change entries with 4 or 5 digits at the end.

Comment: Does the URL to be updated is always *tag `[LINK]`, multiple opening tags enclosed in square brackets, `https://` followed by correct path finished with slash, 4 or 5 digits, multiple closing tags enclosed in square brackets, tag `[/LINK]`*? And maybe the URL path is always `https://example.com/images/`?

Comment: As in my example above, like id=6, it can also be that the URL is not directly surrounded by a [LINK]-Tag. I'll add another example in the question. But the URL's itself look all the same scheme -> https://example.com/images/{4-5 digit number}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Regular expressions in MySQL, from 8.0 and on:

```
SELECT message AS original, REGEXP_REPLACE(message, '((http://|https://).*/images/[0-9]+)', '$1.png') AS new
  FROM Post 
  WHERE message REGEXP '.*(http://|https://).*/images/([0-9]{4,5})(?![0-9]).*'
```

The where clause simply finds matches where `https:// or 'http://` is found, followed by `any characters` followed by `/images/`, followed by `any number, 4 or 5 times`, followed by a `[, or a letter or space` then any characters.

*The `(?![0-9])` is important as the `.*` will match any characters, including numbers. So without it, matches with 6+ numbers would be found. It basically means "Anything but a number".*

The regexp is using a capture group to capture everything before the numbers, and replace it with itself, plus the `.png`.

### Results given your example:

```
Here is your image link: [LINK]https://example.com/images/1234.png[/LINK] You can view it now.
Here is your image link: [LINK]https://example.com/images/5678.png[/LINK] You can view it now.
[LINK][IMG]https://example.com/images/9123.png[/IMG][/LINK]
[LINK]Some text https://example.com/images/23456.png Text again[/LINK]
[URL="https://example.com/images/10796.png"]
```

**DBFiddle**

https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=4qC2I51yju

### Edit: The above won't work in MariaDB

Becuase you are using MariaDB 10, Taking a look at the reference for the REGEXP_REPLACE function: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/regexp_replace/

You need to use `\\1`, not `$1`. So replace `$1.png` with `\\1.png` if you are using MariaDB.

**Final query used to update:**

```
UPDATE Post SET message = REGEXP_REPLACE(message, '((http://|https://).*/images/[0-9]+)', '$1.png')
      WHERE message REGEXP '.*(http://|https://).*/images/([0-9]{4,5})(?!0-9]).*';
```

*Change `$1.png` to `\\1.png` for MariaDB*

Comment: Thanks @dustytrash for the answer. On the new row, i get for example that after the query: [LINK][url]$1.png[/url] [/LINK]. In addition i saw, that some URL's does have a whitespace between the URL ID and the [/LINK]-Tag.

Comment: It does also touch entries which contains such URL's [LINK]https://example.com/images/146818616741951.png[/LINK]

Comment: Great, it worked for most of the entries. Now i saw some which are in that format [URL="https://example.com/images/10796"] which have not changed. I edited my question and added an example.

Comment: Yes it worked!! You're my hero, thank you so much @dustytrash